# Call C binary with multiple instances from bash file depending on the input csv files

Tags: bash

I have one bash script which will call the multiple instances of c executable depending on number of csv files present in the directory. eg. if 3 csv files are present then bash script then it will call 3 instances of c executable and so on. Each instance will process one file parallelly and independently. There will be maximum 3 input files present in the directory at a time.

But before calling multiple instances I need to perform some validation on each file like file_name is in correct format ,file_seq_no is correct. The validation on each input file will be different.

I have written the logic in bash script as

If first input file is present:

1. Perform validation on input_file_1 (like validate file_seq_no is correct).
2. If everything is correct call c executable with  : C_executable $input_file_1

If second input file if present

1. Perform validation on input_file_2.
2. If everything is correct call c executable with  : C_executable $input_file_2

Similarly if 3rd file present

1. Perform validation on input_file_3.
2. If everything is correct call c excutable with  : C_executable $input_file_3

Will this call the c_executable in parallel or sequentially (like will process $input file 1 first then 2 and then 3) ?

Kindly suggest better solution if available?

Comment: It will execute sequentially unless the C_executable backgrounds itself. To run in parallel, you can use `&` in bash to force the C_executable to background itself. To handle errors or receive feedback from C_executable, you will need more sophisticated code.

Comment: If you want to execute something in the background so that your script can continue while it is running you can put a & at the end of the command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/launch-a-background-process-and-check-when-it-ends 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122460/bash-how-to-let-some-background-processes-run-but-wait-for-others https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276020/how-do-i-start-a-background-process-from-a-shell-script-and-log-the-output-of-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure you will only have 3 files, then you can keep it simple and avoid a loop.  You could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

function validate
{
    # Do some validation
    echo "TODO validation"
}
#######################################

file1="filename1.csv"
if [[ -f "$file1" ]]
then
    validate "$file1"
    ./C_executable "$file1" &
fi

file2="filename2.csv"
if [[ -f "$file2" ]]
then
    validate "$file2"
    ./C_executable "$file2" &
fi

file3="filename3.csv"
if [[ -f "$file3" ]]
then
    validate "$file3"
    ./C_executable "$file3" &
fi
```

- The `validate` function can contain whatever you require.
- The `&` sends the `C_executable` into the background.  So they will all run at the same time (i.e. in parallel).
- If you omit `&`, everything will happen sequentially.
- If `C_executable` sends any output, it will appear in your terminal.  If you have more than one running, all the output will be mixed in the same terminal.
- Make sure `C_executable` does not use temporary files that have the same name, otherwise each instance will interfere with the others.